# getting node to start on linux

Tags: linux, node.js

I followe this guide to intall node https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#building-on-linux

I exported my path like this:

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

then get this version back:

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# node -v
v0.13.0-pre
```

I then try to start node server like this `node .`, but get this:

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# node .
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/bin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:10)
    at startup (node.js:132:16)
    at node.js:817:3
```

why isn't node server able to start?

Comment: Because you're giving it an invalid argument? It should be `node script.js` or just `node` if you want the REPL.

Comment: if I do type in just `node`, I do get to node command line...but i don't believe the nodejs server is running..how do make sure the node server is running?

Comment: @user2061886 try installing learnyounode this is a set of tutorials for understanding the node.js

Comment: "node server" isn't a thing. You might have a `server.js` file that you can run using `node server.js`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node itself is a program which reads your script and executes it, as such it is not really a server, as Ben Fortune said you need to pass the argument to it (the program which will be running by the node VM). The program itself determines what your server will be doing.

If you want a quick information on how to use the node.js please install the learnyounode from [this](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) page this will explain how to write basic http servers using node js.